# Combining two dicts into a list

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries,i want to combine these two int a list in the format keys-->values,keys-->values... remove any None or ['']

currently I have the below where I can combine the dicts but not create a combined lists...i have the expecte output..
any inputs appreeciated

```
dict1={'313115': ['313113'], '311957': None}
dict2={'253036': [''], '305403': [], '12345': ['']}

dict = dict(dict1.items() + dict2.items())
print dict

{'313115': ['313113'], '311957': None, '253036': [''], '12345': [''], '305403': []}

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
['313115','313113','311957','253036','305403','12345']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[i for k, v in (dict1.items() + dict2.items()) for i in [k] + (v or []) if i]
```

walk the combined items of the two dicts, then walk the key plus the list of values, returning each item from the second walk that exists.

Returns `['313115', '313113', '311957', '253036', '12345', '305403']` on your example dicts -- the order is different because python's dict iteration is unordered.

EDIT:

`dict.items()` can be expensive on large dicts -- it takes O(n) size, rather than iterating.  If you use itertools, this is more efficient (and keeps the dicts you're working with in one place):

```
import itertools
[i
 for k, v in itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in (dict1, dict2))
 for i in [k] + (v or [])
 if i]
```

Thanks to Martijn Pieters for the from_iterable tip.

Comment: @kevinn - above doesnt print anything,where is the print happening?

Comment: It doesn't print anything.  You'll have to do something with the result yourself (like printing it).

Comment: Python's sets don't allow duplicates, so just do `set(your_list)`.  Or, use a set comprehension instead of a list comprehension to discard duplicate elements immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The following line gives you what you want in as efficient a manner as possible, albeit a little verbose:

```
from itertools import chain, ifilter

list(ifilter(None, dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys() | set(chain(chain.from_iterable(ifilter(None, dict1.itervalues())), chain.from_iterable(ifilter(None, dict2.itervalues()))))))
```

You could break it down to:

```
values1 = chain.from_iterable(ifilter(None, dict1.itervalues()))
values2 = chain.from_iterable(ifilter(None, dict2.itervalues()))
output = list(ifilter(None, dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys() | set(chain(values1, values2))))
```

`ifilter` with a `None` filter removes false-y values such as `None` and `''` from the iterable. the outer filter is not needed for your specific input but would remove `''` and `None` if used as keys as well. Duplicate values are removed.

Ordering in Python dictionaries is arbitrary so ordering doesn't match your sample but all expected values are there.

Demo:

```
>>> list(ifilter(None, dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.viewkeys() | set(chain(chain.from_iterable(ifilter(None, dict1.itervalues())), chain.from_iterable(ifilter(None, dict2.itervalues()))))))
['313115', '305403', '313113', '311957', '253036', '12345']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[each
 if isinstance(each,  str) else each[0]
 for pair in dict(dict1, **dict2).iteritems()
 for each in pair
 if each not in [[''], None, []]]
```